# How can I select certain rows in a dataset? Mathematica

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica, rows

My question is probably really easy, but I am a mathematica beginner.

I have a dataset, lets say:

1. Column: Numbers from 1 to 10
2. Column Signs
3. Column Other signs.

   {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{d,t,4,/,g,t,w,o,p,m},{g,h,j,k,l,s,d,e,w,q}}

Now I want to extract all rows for which column 1 provides an odd number. In other words I want to create a new dataset.

I tried to work with `Select` and `OddQ` as well as with the IF function, but I have absolutely no clue how to put this orders in the right way!

Comment: You need to be carefull with your symbols there in the table (e.g. is `/` a string?). Either way, the way I would do it would be to transpose it twice `Cases[Transpose[mytable], _?(OddQ@#[[1]] &)] // Transpose`

Comment: Possibly related [45429](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45429/select-row-from-a-table-by-column-value), [29334](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29334/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica), [9269](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/the-gap-between-mapat-and-replacepart-for-2d-data-tables-with-headers), [44256](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44256/more-elegant-way)

Comment: just to clarify i suspect you just have a  table, not literally a mathematica `Dataset` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at what you might be asking..

```
 (table = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} ,
     Characters["abcdefghij"],
     Characters["ABCDEFGHIJ"]}) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
 table[[All, 1 ;; -1 ;; 2]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

or perhaps this:

```
 Select[table, OddQ[#[[1]]] &]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Mathematica is the reverse of what you use in your description.
Rows are first level sublists.

Let's take your original data

```
mytable = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{d,t,4,"/",g,t,w,o,p,m},{g,h,j,k,l,s,d,e,w,q}}
```

Just as you suggested, Select and OddQ can do what you want, but on your table, transposed. So we transpose first and back:

```
Transpose[Select[Transpose[mytable], OddQ[First[#]]& ]]
```

Another way:
Mathematica functional command `MapThread` can work on synchronous lists.

```
DeleteCases[MapThread[If[OddQ[#1], {##}] &, mytable], Null]
```

The inner function of MapThread gets all elements of what you call a 'row' as variables (#1, #2, etc.). So it test the first column and outputs all columns or a Null if the test fails. The enclosing DeleteCases suppresses the unmatching "rows".